# What is the definition of a wedge of simplicial complexes?

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition

From Rotman's **Algebraic Topology** concerning the wedge operator:

> If $K_1$ and $K_2$ are simplicial complexes, then for all $n \ge 1$, $$H_n(K_1 \lor K_2) \cong H_n(K_1) \oplus H_n(K_2)$$

What is the definition of the wedge of two simplicial complexes $K_1 \lor K_2$?  Directly above this problem Rotman defines the wedge of two pointed spaces to be the quotient space of their disjoint union with identified basepoints.

If we take $K_i$ as pointed spaces then they're a finite disjoint union of elements $s$ (simplexes of $K_i$) and therefore their nontrivial homology groups should be $0$, but it may be the case that $H_n(K_i)$ is not $0$ so I do not see how this could be an appropriate definition.

Comment: It is not clear to me what is meant by the first sentence of the second paragraph. In general, a pointed simplicial complex is not a disjoint union of simplices.

Comment: To clarify my current understanding:  If $K$ is a $k$-simplex and all of its subfaces, then if we take $K'$ to be the pointed space made from $K$, it must be the case that if $x$ is an element of $K'$ then $x$ must be a simplex of $K$.  But $x \cap x' = \emptyset$ unless $x = x'$ as $x$ and $x'$ are just points of $K'$ as different points are not the same point.

Comment: In the book Rotman defines the space $|K| = \bigcup_{s \in K} s$ as the disjoint union of simplexes from the simplicial complex viewed as a subspace of the ambient Euclidean space.  Are you saying he means to show that $H_n(|K_1| \lor |K_2|) \cong ...$?

Comment: The way I think is a simplicial complex is a collection of simplicies where some pairs of faces of simplices are glued together. A rigorous definition might start with a disjoint collection of simplices and glue them together with attaching maps. So a square is a simplicial complex made of four 1-simplices and four 0-simplices. It is a topological space so we can make it pointed by choosing a basepoint - this basepoint should be a 0-simplex. So the wedge of two squares is a pair of squares that share a common vertex with eight 1-simplices and seven 0-simplices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wedge of pointed simplicial complexes is obtained (as for topological spaces) by identifying the two "points," which in this case are 0-simplices. With this definition, $|K_1| \vee |K_2|$ is homeomorphic to $|K_1 \vee K_2|$.

By 'identifying the two "points," ' I mean: we may assume that $K_1$ and $K_2$ are disjoint. If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are the distinguished 0-simplices in $K_1$ and $K_2$, then you create a new simplicial complex, replacing both of these with a single 0-simplex $w$, and the simplices in this new complex are the simplices in either $K_1$ or $K_2$, except you replace $v_i$ with $w$ wherever it appears. (I'm viewing simplices as being defined by their vertices, so if $(v_1, x, y, z)$ is a simplex in $K_1$, then $(w, x, y, z)$ will be a simplex in $K_1 \vee K_2$.)